# Create a channel from an array

Tags: arrays, go, channel

What is the simplest way to add all the elements of an array to a channel?

I can do this:

```
elms := [3]int{1, 2, 3}
c := make(chan int, 3)

for _, e := range elms {
    c <- e
}
```

But I wonder if there is a syntactic sugar for this.

Comment: this is a valid question and not just for ease-of-use. When you know how many elements will be added you can pre-allocate buffers and avoid excessive garbage collection due to reallocations. The important information here though is the capacity, not the actual contents of the array. You already provided a capacity for your channel.

Comment: *Channels* though aren't collections, even if they can be used like that. As the name implies, they are a channel of communication between processes/workers. The capacity specifies how many items can be queued before blocking. If the consumer is fast enough you won't need a large capacity even if you send a large array to the  channel. The capacity is needed to *prevent* the producer from flooding the channel with unprocessed messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code should be correct, maintainable, robust, reasonably efficient, and, most importantly, readable.

By design, Go is simple, but powerful. Everybody can read and memorize the specification: [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors). You can learn Go in a day or so. The simplicity makes Go code very readable.

The complexity of syntactic sugar induces cognitive overload. After working alongside [Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/) (C++) and [Guido van Rossum](https://gvanrossum.github.io/) (Python), the Go authors deliberately avoided syntactic sugar.

Read Bjarne Stroustrup's recent lament about the complexity of C++: [Remember the Vasa!](http://www.stroustrup.com/P0977-remember-the-vasa.pdf).

It's easy to see what this code does:

```
package main

func main() {
    elms := [3]int{1, 2, 3}
    c := make(chan int, len(elms))
    for _, elm := range elms {
        c <- elm
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In [Golang Spec on Channels](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types) It is defined as:-

> A single channel may be used in send statements, receive operations,
>   and calls to the built-in functions cap and len by any number of
>   goroutines without further synchronization.

There is one more way to assign complete slice or array to the channel as:

```
func main() {
    c := make(chan [3]int)

    elms := [3]int{1, 2, 3}

    go func() {
        c <- elms
    }()

    for _, i := range <-c {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

Check working example on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/14RECb5xS5h)

For information on channels view this link https://dave.cheney.net/tag/golang-3